# BigQuery error message--Not found: Dataset shaley-397718:bigquery-public-data was not found in location US

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am having an issue with BigQuery. I have checked the location of these datasets and it's showing the US but then BigQuery returns this error msg

> Not found: Dataset shaley-397718:bigquery-public-data was not found in location US.

I have tried to change the location but I don't know how to go about it. Below is part of the code I am trying to run.

```
FROM
    bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_education_international_education AS edu
INNER JOIN
    bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_international_education.country_summary AS summary
ON edu.country_code=summary.country_code
```

I have also tried running this code with backticks included but to no avail, I have tried enclosing it in brackets and yet nothing.

Comment: If you are using BigQuery, as your question and title suggests, why have you also tagged [[tag:sql-server]]?

Comment: You defined your first table wrong: bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_education.international_education

Comment: Yes @DanielZagales you are right and there was also a repetition of words on the inner join statement..       **bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_international_education.country_summary** instead of 
  **bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_education.country_summary**...        my brain was quite satiated as at when I was running that query that I couldn't point them out.. thanks guys